# UI.Sortable: Default position/index when receiving a UI.Draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

**Description**:

I have two Infragistics DataGrids, one is `UI.Sortable` and accepts rows from the second Grid which is `UI.Draggable`.

I use the `receive` Event to get the dropped, new rows position/index inside of the grid to perform a server-request to re-order the rows in the database accordingly.

It all works great, as long as I drop rows between the existing rows in the first grid. When I drop a row further down in the grid (the grid itself consists of multiple HTML table elements and a containing `div` tag), the row is dropped to the end of the grid (which is the desired behaviour), but the index/position that I get is always '1'.

**Code:**

```js
var newItem; 
$("#tbl2 tr").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#tbl",
    helper: 'clone'
});

$("#tbl").sortable({
    revert: true,             
    items: "tr",

    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        newItem = ui.item;
    },            
    receive: function (event, ui) {

        $newOrder = $(newItem).parent().children().index(newItem);
        alert($newOrder);
     }
}).disableSelection();
```

```html
<div id="tbl">
    <table id="dataTbl">
        <tr><td><b>Test1</b></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<table id="tbl2">
    <tr><td><b>Test1</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Demo** (Simplified, I use `tables` instead of `WebDataGrid` and put a `div` around the first table to reproduce the same behaviour)

http://jsfiddle.net/4gLxH/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [nikoshr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071630/nikoshr) pointed out, your sortable is the container `div#tbl`, not the table inside it. Hence the item will be appended to the `div#tbl`.

His [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24342510/2333214) is a possible workaround. However, if you actually want the container `div#tbl` to be the sortable, append the dropped items to the table in it and retrieve the index based on the table as in your current setup, you can update your receive handler as follows:

```
function (event, ui) {
   if(!$(newItem).parent().is('tbody')) // check whether it's a drop in container or not
        $(this).children('#dataTbl').append(newItem.remove()); //it so manually append the item to table
   $newOrder = $(newItem).parent().children().index(newItem);
   alert($newOrder);
 }
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4gLxH/15/)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer offered a copy-paste solution for my problem, even with the WebDataGrid!

Answer (score 1):

Your sortable, `#tbl`, is not a table, but a `div` containing the actual table. This means that, in certain conditions, the dragged rows can be dropped outside of the table and  `$(newItem).parent().children()` are the children of the container, not the rows.

A simple fix would be to use your table as the sortable, something like this

```
var $receiver = $("#tbl").find('table');

$receiver.sortable({
    // ...
}).disableSelection();
```

and connect the draggables to this table :

```
$("#tbl2 tr").draggable({
    connectToSortable: $receiver,
    helper: 'clone'
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/dn7Z4/ for a demo.

Comment: Thank you! You were totally right about the problem, but as Tilwin pointed out, would make the table sortable and not the div. But thank you!